# scheme: Wrong type argument in position

Tags: scheme, guile

I'd really appreciate it if some-one can help with this. I've been banging my head for a day trying to get this to work. I've searched the internet and reread the manual but I just don't understand.

```
guile << __EOF__

( define heading-list (list 'a 'b 'c)
)

(define (make-heading-list)
  ( let* ((mycond #t))
     ( if mycond
       ( set! 
           heading-list
           ( append (
               heading-list
               (list 'd)
             )
           )
       )
       ( display 'false)
    )
    heading-list
  )
)

(make-heading-list)
__EOF__
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ERROR: In procedure setter:
ERROR: In procedure setter: Wrong type argument in position 1: (a b c)
```

I know the formatting is non-std - I'll fix it when it works.

EDIT-----------------------------------------
Here is working code (hopefully reasonably formatted now):

```
guile << __EOF__

(define heading-list (list 'a 'b 'c))

(define (make-heading-list)
  (let* ((mycond #t))
        (if mycond
           (set!
               heading-list
               (append heading-list (list 'd)))
           (display 'false))
         heading-list))

(make-heading-list)
__EOF__
```

Comment: You have an extra set of parens around `heading-list` in both places. Don’t write your parens like that; it makes such problems harder to pick out. Also, overall your code seems odd in a few places... why bind `mycond` to `#t`, then branch on it? Why the `set!` instead of just returning a list?

Comment: Hi Alexis. Thanks for your help. I removed parens around both heading-list's in function make-heading-list. Now getting: `ERROR: In procedure (a b c):
ERROR: Wrong type to apply: (a b c)`   I'm using mycond because this is a simplified test of what I really want to do and I wanted to test the if. I'm using the set! because I couldn't get anything else to work either. Suggestions welcome - especially example code!

Comment: Could you update your question with your updated code? That would be helpful, I think.

Comment: Alexis: Original code updated.

Comment: You still have an extra set of parens around the `(heading-list (list 'd))` expression, which is also attempting to invoke `heading-list` as a procedure.

Comment: Alexis: Working now thanks! If you want to submit an answer, I'll accept it. Michaels answer below is also correct.

Comment: Nah, it’s fine. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heading-list` is a list. You are using it as if it were a procedure. `(heading-list)` means "apply procedure `heading-list` to zero arguments". Hence the error message "wrong type to apply".

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried removing the parens but get different error - see comment above. I understand what you're saying but I don't know how to fix...

Comment: You are still using `heading-list` as a procedure in `append`. It should be `(append heading-list (list 'd))`.

Comment: Michael, Working now thanks! And I think I understand why. It seems so simple now...

Comment: It **is** simple. That's the beauty of scheme.